# Catch execute result from R script

Tags: python, r, return

I have an R script that I call it from Python, and I want to capture the output from it. I can write to CMD, as well as TXT, but I would like to capture the output in Python script so I can work with it.

In python script I have tried with:

```
logging.debug (os.popen ('Rscript testScript.r'))
```

But it doesn't work. I have also tried with:

```
output = cmd ('Rscript testScript.r')

print (output)
```

But it returns *None* as output.

In R I have tried with: `returnValue (TRUE)` but it writes to the CMD, and the output is still *None*.

How can I make the R script return a value that I can filter to see the result ???

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

In R we can put the option inside a **`Try/catch`**

```
  error = function (cond)
```

This reflects an output that in Python we can collect as:

```
  print (stderr)
  print (stdout)
```

Where **`stderr`** is the output error and **`stdout`** is the standard output.

Hope if anyone has a similar problem it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a solution to the same problem, I came across using

```
out <- "some string or dataframe or anything else"
write(out, stdout())
```

in R.

According to your example in python:

```py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run(
    ['Rscript', 'testScript.r'],
    capture_output = True,
    text = True
    )
print(output.stdout)
```

the desired output would be stored in the stdout-attribute.

Comment: Since I wasn't able to replicate the authors solution, I came up with this one. This way there would be no need to use the tryCatch-Block in R if it's not desired.